# Best practice for packaging Python bindings with fallback implementation (PEP 518)

Tags: python, c++, cmake, setuptools, pybind11

Let's consider the following example.
There's a static C++ library libFoo, distributed as a CMake sub-project.
Now, there's a Python implementation of Foo, called pyFoo, which should provide Python bindings for libFoo (using pybind11),
but does also provide a pure Python implementation of Foo's capabilities, in case libFoo cannot be build
on the target platform.

The repository for such a project would look like this:

```
 +--+ libFoo
 |  +--- CMakeLists.txt (export a static library target foo::foo)
 |  +--- src/..., inc/... (c++ sources for libFoo)
 |
 +--+ pyFoo
    +--- pyproject.toml
    +--- ... (other metadata/package files, tests, etc)
    +--+ foo (main package dir)
       +--+ _native
       |  +--- CMakeLists.txt (imports libFoo/CMakeLists.txt as a subproject, configures, adds pybind11 module)
       |  +--- foo_bindings.cpp (literally pybind11 bindings using imported foo::foo)
       |
       +--- _fallback/... (pure Python implementation of libFoo for compatibility)
       +--- __init__.py (essentially "try: from ._native.foo_bindings import *; except ImportError: from ._fallback import *")
```

Now, while this kind of structure worked for me as a development environment (`pyFoo/foo/_native` CMake moves compiled foo_bindings into an appropriate place upon `ninja install`),
this doesn't seem like a proper way to handle building the native (C++) part for the sake of creating distributions and wheels.

I did some research on how other packages handle these kinds of situations, but I could only find the following scenarios:

- The package is just a lib + binding, (no pure Python implementation), so native build is required for setup;
- The package imports an external library (e.g. libssl.so) using ctypes/cffi and falls back to Python implementation if the import fails, so from the point of view of the build system, it's a pure Python package.

What I'm trying to achieve here, is to have a package that will work in as many scenarios as possible, including cases where users may not be able to compile C++ sources (e.g. Windows without MSVC) *and* wheels are not available for their platforms.

How would I go about specifying that using as many modern tools/solutions (think using PEP 518 instead of putting everything into setup.py) as possible,
while keeping the interface simple and clean?

A desired decision tree for a `pip install pyfoo` would be:

- If there is a wheel for the current platform, use it
- If there is no wheel, try building `foo._native.bindings` from source (using CMake), including direct dependency of `libfoo`.

  - If the build succeeds, everything's all right, use foo._native.bindings in the final setup
  - If the build fails, don't break setup, instead install everything except for the `foo._native` package.

**Bonus question**: If `foo._fallback` has an additional package dependencies (beyond what `foo`/`foo._native` require), is it a good practice to list them in `pyproject.toml` if the default implementation is that in `foo._native`?

General pointers would be OK. I've looked through several articles on the matter, but they seem to be incomplete, or rather basic.
For instance [https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-binary-extensions/] even gives the following example:

> Example: When importing datetime, Python falls back to the datetime.py module if the C implementation ( _datetimemodule.c) is not available.

but then fails to address this scenario in the body.

Comment: Asking for _best practice_ at such a high level automatically makes your question not focussed enough, and opinionated.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which is why I started my question with a concrete example and asked for explicit pointers/guides and not opinions.